# Advice for Australian with dual citizenship (US/Australia) married to a US citizen and they move to Australia

Tags: taxes, australia

If both myself (dual citizen usa/australia) and my husband (us citizen) are living in Australia and we each make over $150,000USD per year - are we really in a bad spot with US taxes and getting double taxed since we make quite a bit more than the Foreign Earned Income Exclusion (FEIE) allows for? Hard to understand how we would have any money left :(

Comment: Is renouncing US Citizenship an option?

Comment: With how high the exclusion is and how low taxes are, your net income would still be several times my gross income....